# How can I choose the right number of epochs per trial in Optuna?

Tags: optuna

Is there a rule of thumb for how to choose the number of epochs per trial in [Optuna](https://optuna.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine epochs are directly correlated with your computational costs, but perhaps that's a parameter worth optimizing. If you aren't sure, start with your best guess and run a few optimization studies with different epoch values. Once you confirm the importance of your epochs, you can conduct separate studies on just the epoch value.